# Why is there a table scan even though I have index on IGroupes table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, rdbms

This is my query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'set arithabort off;set statistics time on; set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;With cte as (Select peta_rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  d.LastStatusChangedDateTime  desc )  
                                                , d.DocumentID,
                                                d.IsReEfiled, d.IGroupID, d.ITypeID, d.RecordingDateTime, d.CreatedByAccountID, d.JurisdictionID, 
                                                d.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                                                ,  d.IDate, d.InstrumentID, d.DocumentStatusID
                                                , u.Username
                                                , it.Abbreviation AS ITypeAbbreviation
                                                , ig.Abbreviation AS IGroupAbbreviation,
                                                d.DocumentDate                                               
                                From Documents d                             
                                Inner Join ITypes it  on it.ITypeID = d.ITypeID
                                 Inner Join Users u on d.UserID = u.UserID Inner Join IGroupes ig on ig.IGroupID = d.IGroupID
                                Where 1=1  And  (  d.DocumentStatusID = 9  ) ) Select cte.DocumentID, 
                                cte.IsReEfiled, cte.IGroupID, cte.ITypeID, cte.RecordingDateTime, cte.CreatedByAccountID, cte.JurisdictionID, 
                        cte.LastStatusChangedDateTime as LastStatusChangedDateTime
                        ,  cte.IDate, cte.InstrumentID, cte.DocumentStatusID,cte.IGroupAbbreviation, cte.Username, j.JDAbbreviation, inf.DocumentName,
                       cte.ITypeAbbreviation, cte.DocumentDate, ds.Abbreviation as DocumentStatusAbbreviation,  ds.Name as DocumentStatusName,
                        ( SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN cte.DocumentID = (
                                SELECT TOP 1 doc.DocumentID
                                FROM  Documents doc
                                WHERE doc.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID
                                        AND doc.DocumentStatusID = cte.DocumentStatusID
                                ORDER BY LastStatusChangedDateTime) 
                            THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS BIT)
                        ) AS CanChangeStatus ,

                        Upper((Select Top 1 Stuff( (Select ''='' + dbo.GetDocumentNameFromParamsWithPartyType(Business, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, t.Abbreviation, NameTypeID, pt.Abbreviation, IsGrantor, IsGrantee)  From DocumentNames dn
                                Left Join Titles t
                                    on dn.TitleID = t.TitleID               
                                Left Join PartyTypes pt
                                    On pt.PartyTypeID = dn.PartyTypeID
                                        Where DocumentID = cte.DocumentID
                                            For XML PATH('''')),1,1,''''))) as FlatDocumentName, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE) AS TotalRecords

                        FROM cte Left Join DocumentStatuses ds On
                        cte.DocumentStatusID = ds.DocumentStatusID Left Join InstrumentFiles inf On cte.DocumentID = inf.DocumentID 
                    Left Join Jurisdictions j on j.JurisdictionID = cte.JurisdictionID Where 1=1 And 
                    peta_rn>@7 AND peta_rn<=@8 Order by peta_rn set statistics time off; ',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 int,@4 int,@5 int,@6 int,@7 int,@8 int',
                    @0=1,@1=5,@2=9,@3=1,@4=5,@5=9,@6=1,@7=97500,@8=97550
```

And this is my IGroupes table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IGroupes](
    [IGroupID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [JurisdictionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Abbreviation] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IGroupes] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [IGroupID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_IGroupes_Abbreviation]    Script Date: 10/11/2013 4:21:46 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IGroupes_Abbreviation] ON [dbo].[IGroupes]
(
    [Abbreviation] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [IGroupID],
    [Name],
    [JurisdictionID]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_IGroupes_JurisdictionID]    Script Date: 10/11/2013 4:21:46 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IGroupes_JurisdictionID] ON [dbo].[IGroupes]
(
    [JurisdictionID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [IGroupID],
    [Name],
    [Abbreviation]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_IGroupes_Name]    Script Date: 10/11/2013 4:21:46 AM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IGroupes_Name] ON [dbo].[IGroupes]
(
    [Name] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [IGroupID],
    [JurisdictionID],
    [Abbreviation]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Yet please see it is using table scan. This operation is costing me too much. `IGroupes` table just has 7 rows and `Documents` table has approximately 98K records. Yet when I join on `d.IGroupID = ig.IGroupID` it shows actual number of rows above 600K! That is the problem. Please see the attached screenshot:

[image]

In case anybody is interested in the full query plan xml, here it is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kldx24x3j8vndpe/plan.xml

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you can't create the PK as clustered? That might help, and is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @usr: Mistakenly I had deleted it. Thanks! It now shows clustered index scan. I want to convert it to seek. Is there any way?

Comment: That's very strange. In the execution plan it appears there is a simple predicate on the ID column. Can you post the new plan with the CI?

Comment: Do you have updated statistics? Did you try moving the join to IGroups out of the CTE?

Comment: usr: I appreciate your help. Here is the new plan: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3su1httra01h9gi/new%20plan.txt

Comment: I need to find a way why is the actual number of rows above 600K. My documents table just has 100K rows and IGroupes is my lookup table with just 7 rows. Why would that result in 600K rows? :S

Comment: @Lieven: I need the join inside CTE since this is dynamic SQL and I may order by ig.Abbreviation instead of LastStatusDatetime and yes this morning I did use this command sp_updatestats so I guess it's updated.

Comment: I'm unable to work it out. Everything is as it should be. The index should be perfect. I found one clue: the reason that the optimizer ended optimizing is "Time Out". That means that the query is so complex that the optimizer decided not to spend more time. Try this: only run the part of the query that sits below the top operator (that's the problematic branch). Include the top. When running that you should see a better plan for this subtree because we might be lucky enough to avoid the timeout.

Comment: Alternatively, split the query into multiple smaller queries that work together using temp tables. That's an ugly solution of last resort, but should also help the plan.

Comment: @usr and Lieven: I ended up to force seek by adding a where clause: **And ig.IGroupID > 0 And ig.Abbreviation IS NOT NULL**. It is pointless but it seems to work. I now get results in 450 ms. A good 300 ms saved with a pointless but *working* clause :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the 3 indexes (other than the PK) you have on `IGroupes` are going to help this query because you are not using any of those fields in a where or join clause. Unless you need those indexes for other queries, I would delete them. They are just going to give the query optimizer more choices to test (and reject).

The index on the Primary Key `PK_IGroupes` should be clustered. That will allow it to do an index seek (or bookmark lookup). If it can't be clustered for some other reason, try creating an index on `IGroupID` and `Abbreviation`, in that order (or including the `Abbreviation` column in the existing PK index).

If it still doesn't pick up the right index, you can use a hint such as `WITH(INDEX(0))` or `WITH(INDEX('index-name'))`.

The 600k rows does come from the fact that it is doing a nested loop join on 98k rows multiplied by the 7 rows. If the index above doesn't work, you can try replacing the `INNER JOIN iGroupes` with `INNER HASH JOIN IGroupes`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably in this case table scan is more efficient than using any of the indexes you have on the `IGroupes` table.
If you think table scan operation is bottleneck in this query (though with 3% cost I'm not sure it is) either you may try modifying `PK_IGroupes` to become clustered index or you may try index like

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IGroupes_IGroupID]
    ON [dbo].[IGroupes] ([IGroupID]) INCLUDE ([Abbreviation])
```

Comment: I tried this solution and make IGroupID as clustered. Now it shows clustered index scan. I want to convert it to seek. Is there any way?

Comment: @Jack, scan is not necessarily mean something that is worse than seek. For example if all table or index data is queried scan is quite often appear instead of seek.

Comment: I cannot come up with a situation in which a CI scan would be preferable to a CI seek if seeking on the key is possible.

Comment: @i-phone: I understand but I am only querying for Abbreviation and it is already in INCLUDE as you posted in the NCI definition.

Comment: @i-phone: I am only worrying so much about this as my query speed is almost reduced to half if I don't join in IGroupes (A small table with 7 rows) As you can see actual number of rows is above 600K and I am totally unable to understand why would that happen. It is a simple lookup table with 7 rows and it doubles my query speed :(. If I don't join on Igroupes I get my results back in 300 ms in 100K record table and if I join I get it in 700 ms. A considerable difference for a lookup table :(

Comment: @Jack, 600K can be related to a loop operator (98K rows 7 times). You may try specify `merge` or `hash` hint manually, likely you will see adequate actual number of rows, though it may affect performance negatively